# Getting Delphi to read a database with a new version of Microsoft Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010

We use a Delphi 10 programme that reads in an Access database. I do not deeply understand how it does it, except that I believe it uses units called DAO.pas and DAO_TLB.pas.

I recently upgraded from Office 2007 to Office 2016, and since then the Delphi programme is unable to read from the database; it gives the error:

> Project MyProj.exe raised exception class EOleSysError with message 'Class not registered'.

I have tried to search to find how to fix this but am struggling because I don't really understand what's going on under the hood. I tried to install the Access 2016 type library, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Extremely grateful for any help.

Thanks,
Tom

EDIT: DAO.pas is [here](https://pastebin.com/AjH4DDB4). DAO_TLB.pas is where the error is triggered; the function which errors is:

```
class function CoDBEngine.Create: _DBEngine;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_DBEngine) as _DBEngine;
end;
```

Where CLASS_DBEngine is a constant declared as:

```
CLASS_DBEngine: TGUID = '{CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419}';
```

I have also just noticed that, when the error occurs, if I click continue rather than break, a new error appears, saying:

> Class not registered, ClassID: {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419}

i.e. the ClassID is the CLASS_DBEngine constant.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the stacktrace, not just the message box that is displayed for the user. Apart from that, while I know of no "DAO.pas", accessing Access files with FireDAC has proven easy enough for me.

Comment: As said @GünthertheBeautiful you should share with us your DAO.pas file, or try another way of connection to Access.

Comment: Hi all - thanks very much for your comments. I have edited the main post with more information. We have not implemented a stacktrace provider so I don't think I can give you that; apologies.

Comment: 32/64bit issues?

Comment: krish KM - that was it! Thank you! Can't believe I missed that! Greatly appreciated, thank you very much, made a big difference to my day!